# performClick() and callOnClick() doing nothing

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick, click, onclicklistener

I am adding voice commands to an already existing, and fully functioning app. The voice interaction seems to work fine. I am able to say the command, I am getting the correct result, and I am even getting the correct button, which click interaction I want to simulate by using the voice.

My problem is that `performClick()` and `callOnClick()` seem to not even be called. Each button has its Listener (manual clicks work).

As a side note: I am calling the click-methods outside of my activity. Is that a problem?

How do I get these methods to really trigger the onClick's of my buttons?

PS: Maybe some suggestions would be to use the functions direclty instead of using the click-event. The first point, why I don't want to do that, is that I want to avoid duplicate code or a code restructuring, and second, I would like to keep my voice recognition away from being wired too deep into the code by behave like a simple user (hence the programmatical clicking).

EDIT:

Basically I am not doing anything else than:

From my main activity, I am calling my helper class:

```
util = new MainVoiceUtil(this, getLayoutInflater(), viewgroup);
```

`viewgroup`here is unrelated to this topic. In `MainVoiceUtil` it goes:

```
public MainVoiceUtil(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater, Viewgroup viewgroup)
{
   super(context);
   ...
}
```

`MainVoiceUtil` extends `VoiceUtil`, which contains a method `onResult`, which contains the `performClick`. `context` is set in the constructor of `VoiceUtil`. See:

```
@Override
public void onResult(AIResponse result)
{
   View button = ((Activity) context).findViewById(buttonId);
   button.performClick();
}
```

Thanks to log outputs, I know that I have the right button. This means that I know that I am entering the `onResult`-method. All log outputs are shown, just this click does not seem to be executed.

Comment: you can make the button `static` also `public` , use  button.performClick(); directly or callOnClick(). And also check, whether the onclick listener is registered before you call.

Comment: where you are calling performclick() ? in same activity ?

Comment: how can you reference your button (via findViewById(buttonId) ) while that button is outside of your activity, can you describe more specific?

Comment: Setting the button `static` or `public` is not a solution for me, because every button would need that. 

Like I wrote, I am not calling from my activity, I passed the context, got the button, and called `performClick()` on the button (see code).

Comment: @TuấnKiệt I passed the context, got the button by its ID, and called the `performClick()`on it (see code snippet).

Comment: @KJaeg how can you pass a context through an intent? can you show us your code pls?

Comment: @KJaeg I found the solution, check my answer below :)

Comment: @TuấnKiệt I added more detailed code to explain the situation better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was calling the wrong method. The main activity was overriding a method, called `onButtonClick`. This one was deciding by ID, which button was clicked. I thought it was called anyways as soon as an `onClick` was triggered, which didn't seem to be the case. It seems like it goes the other way. By clicking manually, both seem to work together. But in my case I had to go from `button.performClick()` to call `onButtonClick(buttonId)` instead.

I was not familiar with this, hence my confusion. So this was rather a project specific misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

`view.performClick()` worked fine. 
Make sure that you find view and add clicklisterner before call this function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Activity, try to pass your activity . Not the context.

```
Button button =(Button) (youractivity).findViewById(buttonId);//YourActivity.this
button.performClick();
```

This may helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not change anything. 

The only difference now is that I have the danger of running into casting errors due to other clickable widgets, if I don't handle them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I do not recommend calling a button on click from another `Activity` because this is a **very** bad practice.

Although my solution below work fine but I cannot guarantee it will work in case your first activity get destroyed and again It's still a bad practice

My solution:
**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView mTextView;
Button mButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Bridge.setContext(this);
    mTextView = findViewById(R.id.test_text_view);
    mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("MainActivity", "test_text_view onClick() called!");
        }
    });
    mButton = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**SecondActivity**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        button = findViewById(R.id.second_activity_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("SecondActivity", "second_activity_button onClick() called!");
                MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) Bridge.getContext();
                TextView textView = activity.findViewById(R.id.test_text_view);
                textView.performClick();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Bridge**

```
public class Bridge {

    public static Context sContext;

    public static Context getContext() {
        return sContext;
    }

    public static void setContext(Context context) {
        sContext = context;

    }
}
```

[image]
-> Click Hello World!
Logcat:
[image]
Start the second Activity by click BUTTON and then click BUTTON in SecondActivity:
[image]
[image]

My sample project can be found here:
https://github.com/raiytu4/stackcase005

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply, but your solution kinda misses the topic. I am not trying to "copy" `onClick`-functionality to other widgets. I am not leaving my activity. I am still in my activity. My activity is just calling a regular class, which again is trying to `performClick()`. I added more code to make my situation clearer.

But all in all I am doing exactly what you described: I pass the context, get the button, and call `performClick`.

Comment: Have you try to cast the type most specific as possible, something like: **Button** button = ((**YourActivity**) context).findViewById(buttonId);
   button.performClick();
Instead of **View** button = ((**Activity**) context).findViewById(buttonId);
   button.performClick();

Comment: Yes. It didn't change anything. It just created additional effort since I have multiple "clickable" widgets, which are not just buttons. But in my test case it was really a child of the ImageButton class.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set clickListener for that view

```
View button = ((Activity) context).findViewById(buttonId);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // implement your logic
        }
    });

button.performClick();
```

Comment: Like I said, every button already has its clickListener. It's a fully functional app, which customers use productively. So I want to call those existing listeners, not implement new.

Comment: Then you type this 
button.performClick();

Comment: @BhavyaGandhi and this is what does nothing.